# Failed to install npm install -g @tableau/taco-toolkit

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, npm-install

Here is the warning I got: npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm ERR! code 1

I was expecting to install taco

Comment: Please edit your question and provide details of your node and npm versions

Answer (score 0):

Deprecation warnings should not prevent packages from being installed. If you want to resolve the deprecation warning, you'll have to ask the package maintainers to remove the dependency or fork the package.

By the way, you can determine why a deprecated package is being installed with `npm ls`. It will give you a list of all dependencies that rely on a package.

Here's the dependency chain from `@tableau/taco-toolkit` to `stable`

```
> npm install @tableau/taco-toolkit
> npm ls stable                                   
bench@0.1.0 /Users/madison/projects/bench
└─┬ @tableau/taco-toolkit@1.3.0
  └─┬ parcel@2.6.2
    └─┬ @parcel/config-default@2.6.2
      └─┬ @parcel/optimizer-htmlnano@2.6.2
        └─┬ svgo@2.8.0
          └── stable@0.1.8
```